# Google Maps Custom Icons will not load in any Browser

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I used a tutorial to make some custom icons in Google Maps API for some local places. When I am in Dreamweaver and testing on my local server, the icons appear just fine. However, when I upload to my host and try to pull the page up on any browser (safari, chrome, canary, firefox), the images do not load. The placeholders for those images do show, though. I cannot understand what the issue is as I have reloaded and rechecked the code hundreds of times. Any help with this would be appreciated. As the code is very long, I have only included some snippets and the address where it is loaded.

To see the page, go to http://www.theriveroverlook.com/Local.html

I tried to load the code using the forum rules, but no matter what, it would not allow me to put the javascript in this post!

Please let me know if you can help me! This is the last piece of the puzzle I need to load this website! I am a newbie coder so I have made a lot of beginner mistakes!

Edited to add:

**Thank you for your help. When I renamed the folder, it was fixed. For some reason, it did not like the folder name "icons". Perhaps this has something to do with Google's API**

Comment: I get a bunch of 404 (Not Found) errors on that page, like: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.theriveroverlook.com/icons/map_title.png`.  You sure you uploaded your custom icons to the correct place?  Please post the relevant code, not just a link.

Comment: For some reason it did not let me post the code. It said it was in the improper format, even though I followed the instructions. Will try to edit and post it again.

Answer (score 0):

I get the following errors when I load your page:

[image]

Since those are the images you are using to create your custom icons they all fail to generate and won't appear on the map. Make sure you are hosting your images correctly and it should work fine.

Comment: Well, that is a lot simpler of a fix than I was worried it was. This is so strange that they are not going properly onto the hosting using ftp. I shall try again! Thank you!